# Can't get parameters in sqlite / python to work?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am having problems with parameters in sqlite3. The problem comes and goes, so there must be something I am missing. I have tried simplifying my code down to its most basic form but still don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I can get this code to work using string substitutions in the form of `sql = 'SELECT {} FROM {}'.format(col, tbl)` but I understand this is not secure.

Here is a sample code:

```
def check_exists(self, col, tbl):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT ? from ?" , (col, tbl))
        if self.cursor.fetchall():
            return True
        return False
```

Which I run like so:

```
check_exists('type', 'tbl_types')
```

Which raises an exception like so:

```
self.cursor.execute("SELECT ? from ?" , (col, tbl))
OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

My code works fine with explicit parameters:

```
def check_exists(self):
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT * from tbl_types')
        if self.cursor.fetchall():
            return True
        return False

>>> t.check_exists()
True
```

Comment: You cannot parametrize column- or table-names. Being wary of the possibility for SQL-injection attack you could use string-interpolation for the table name.

Comment: Parameters are meant for use in your `where` clause, not for use in determining which columns or tables to select from.

Comment: Makes sense, then is there a significant security risk in using string interpolation for table and column names? What's the standard practice for this type of scenario?

Comment: If you can receive untrusted input to your code yes there is a significant security risk and you are best served using a library like SQLAlchemy.